# Issue with float right in CSS

Tags: css

As you can see on the link, two text are sticky.
...»Dernek Haber 1**By admin on...**

I want to divide these text from each other and the text which starts with "By admin" will be float right.

https://dernek1.deniz-tasarim.site/2019/07/22/dernek-haber-1/ how to solve it?

```
        <style>
             .breadcrumb {
    padding: 8px 15px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border-radius: 4px;

}
.breadcrumb a {
    color: #428bca;
    text-decoration: none;
}





             </style>
<?php

function get_breadcrumb() {
    echo '<a href="'.home_url().'" rel="nofollow">Home</a>';
    if (is_category() || is_single()) {
        echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&#187;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
        the_category(' &bull; ');
            if (is_single()) {
                echo " &nbsp;&nbsp;&#187;&nbsp;&nbsp; ";
                the_title();
            }
    } elseif (is_page()) {
        echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&#187;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
        echo the_title();
    } elseif (is_search()) {
        echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&#187;&nbsp;&nbsp;Search Results for... ";
        echo '"<em>';
        echo the_search_query();
        echo '</em>"';
    }
}
   ?>
             <div class="breadcrumb"><?php get_breadcrumb(); ?>

<div style="float:right;  display:block;">By <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?> on <?php the_time('F jS, Y'); ?>  in <?php the_category(', '); ?> <?php edit_post_link(__('{Edit}'), ''); ?></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add `margin-left: auto;` to the "By admin..." div to solve it.

Like this:

```
<div style="margin-left: auto;">By ... </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
<div class="breadcrumb">
    <div class="first">
        <?php get_breadcrumb(); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="second">
       By <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?> on <?php the_time('F jS, Y'); ?>  in <? 
       php the_category(', '); ?> <?php edit_post_link(__('{Edit}'), ''); ?>
   </div>

 </div>

<style>
    .breadcrumb {
        padding: 8px 15px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        list-style: none;
        background-color: #f5f5f5;
        border-radius: 4px;
        width: 100%;

    }
    .first {
        width: 50%;
    }
    .second {
        text-align: right;
        width: 50%;
    } 
    .breadcrumb a {
        color: #428bca;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

</style>
```

output is : -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

add this to `.breadcrumb` class :

```
.breadcrumb {
    padding: 8px 15px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border-radius: 4px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

and add css `margin-left: auto` to the text :